# Отправка данных в url php

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Стоит вопрос таков, как отправить данные из первой формы во вторую, во второй форме получить еще данные и отправить на третью страницу и все вывести. Решил делать через url. Появилась другая проблема. Как добавить атрибуты к ссылке в form??

получаю значения атрибутов из url на второй форме

```
<?php 
    $url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    return $url;
?>
```

дальше нужно выбрать значение и добавить его к имеющемуся url и перейти на третью страницу
я не могу понять как к "http://x/end.php" добавить значения из  $url

```
<form action="http://x/end.php"  method="GET">
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone 12"> iPhone 12<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone 11"> iPhone 11<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone SE"> iPhone SE<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone XR"> iPhone XR<Br>
<p><input type="submit"" s/></p>
```

Первая форма на первой странице

```
 <form action="http://Lab3Alena/action.php" method="GET">
        <h2 id="buy_apple_products" class="text_buy_apple">Купить продукцию Apple<br></h2>
        <p class="video"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R4-YdC5N6Lo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
        <p>Форма заказа продукции Apple:</p>
        <p>Ваше имя и фамилия: *</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="name_surname" size="40"></p>
        <p>Выберите цвет iPhone:</p>
        <p><select type="type" name="type">
          <option>Белый</option>
          <option>Черный</option>
          <option>Золотой</option>
        </select></p>
        <p>Способ доставки:</p>
        <input type="radio" name="browser" value="Самовывоз"> Самовывоз<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="browser" value="В черте города"> В черте города<Br>
         <input type="radio" name="browser" value="По всей Украине"> По всей Украине<Br>

        <p>Ваш E-mail: *</p>
        <p><input name="email" size="40"></p>
        <p>Ваш адрес: *</p>
        <p><input name="address" size="40"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" /></p>
        <p>* - поля обязательные для заполнения</p>
      </form>
```

Comment: А каким образом данные передаются с формы в форму? Вы просто отправляете её одну за одной?

Comment: action="http://x/action.php" method="GET"
таким образом записываю в url и отправляю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте поля с первой формы(их можно скрыть) подставьте данные с первой формы и отправляйте все вместе.

```
<form action="http://x/end.php"  method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="name_surname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name_surname']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="browser" value="<?php echo $_GET['browser']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="address" value="<?php echo $_GET['address']; ?>">
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone 12"> iPhone 12<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone 11"> iPhone 11<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone SE"> iPhone SE<Br>
        <input type="radio" name="iphone" value="iPhone XR"> iPhone XR<Br>
<p><input type="submit"" s/></p>
```

Comment: Не понял что вы имеете ввиду, можно чуть чуть конкретнее

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov добавил ответ, так понятно?

Comment: простите но нет, видимо не хватает моих знаний в данной области

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov первую форму в студию

Comment: Добавил в сам вопрос

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov надеюсь поняли?)

Comment: В данном случае их можно и динамически циклом добавлять, а не вручную прописывать

Comment: Да понял, все очень доходчиво, спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: Извините, а еще такой вопросик как на последней странице я могу достать все данные ?? чтобы из в бд записать

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov все данные хранятся в глобальной переменной $_GET